# How to get access to from from the controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-form

Consider I have a form , by `ng-form` and a controller -

```js
var myAppModule = angular.module('myApp', []); 
myAppModule.controller('myCtrl',function ($scope) {
          
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-form name="myForm">
  Name : <input ng-model="name" type="text" />
    </div>
</div>
```

How could I get access within the controller - `myCtrl` to the form - `myForm` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$scope.myForm will have the form data

```
var myAppModule = angular.module('myApp', []); 
myAppModule.controller('myCtrl',function ($scope) {
     var form = $scope.myForm;
});
```